# Is there a way to encode a string into base64 in Chrome's Developer tools console

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way in the Developer Tools console to encode a string into Base64?

For example, I would like to do the following:

```
$('input').value = base64Encode("My String");
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To base64 encode a string you can use `btoa` function

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa

For example, use:

```
$('input').value = window.btoa("My String");
```